# In CakePHP how to make Containable behavior cooperate with Tree behavior

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, containable

I have this problem with containable, that I have Categories model that behaves like a tree:

```
class Category extends AppModel {
  public $actsAs = ['Tree', 'Containable'];

  public $hasMany = [
    'Novelty' => [
      'className' => 'Novelty',
      'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
      'dependent' => false,
    ]
  ]
}
```

its structure:

```
Category(
  id int(11)
  name varchar(255)
  parent_id int(11)
  lft int(11)
  rght int(11)
)
```

and i have a Novelty model:

```
class Novelty extends AppModel {
  public $actsAs = ['Containable'];

  public $belongsTo = [
    'Category' => [
      'className' => 'Category',
      'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
    ]
  ];
}
```

Novelty structure:

```
Novelty(
  id int(11)
  name varchar(255)
  category_id int(11)
)
```

Associations

```
Category -> hasMany -> Novlety
Novelty -> belongsTo -> Category
```

Categories example structure from `find('threaded')` is like this:

```
['Category'] => [
  'id' => 13
  'name' => 'Main'
  'lft' => 88
  'rght' => 105
  'children' => [
    [0] => [
      ['Category'] => [
        'id' => 131
        'name' => 'sub1'
        'lft' => 89
        'rght' => 90
      ]
    ]
    [1] => [
      ['Category'] => [
        'id' => 132
        'name' => 'sub2'
        'lft' => 91
        'rght' => 92
      ]
    ]
    [...]
  ]
]
```

And now when I try containable:

```
$this->Category->contain(
  'Novelty' => [
    'conditions' => [
      'AND' => [
        'Novelty.category_id >=' => 13,
        'Novelty.category_id !=' => 14
      ]
    ]
  ]
);
```

Now when i run `Category->find('all')` there are no Novelties in result. Because cake adds its own condition `Novelty.category = (13)`. And I can't get rid nor expand it. So query looks like this:

```
SELECT `Novelty`.`id`, `Novelty`.`name`, `Novelty`.`category_id`, 
FROM `databse`.`novelties` AS `Novelty` 
WHERE ((`Novelty`.`category_id` >= 13) 
  AND (`Novelty`.`category_id` < 14)) 
  AND `Novelty`.`category_id` = (13)
```

Is there any special condition that modifies default query condition?

**My goal:**

To get Novelties that are related to subcategory also, not only those that are related to main category.
But is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now when i run Category->find('all') there are no Novelties in result.
>   Because cake adds its own condition Novelty.category = (13). And I
>   can't get rid nor expand it. So query looks like this:

This is the correct behavior of the code. You have a Cateogry **hasMany** Novelty association, to make this happen Cake adds the condition.

To me it looks like you want to find all Novelty records *except* the ones for category id 14, is that right?

Temporary [unbindModel()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-Model.html#_unbindModel) your Novelty association and add it back as a hasOne assoc without a foreign key but with a condition:

```
['conditions' => ['Novelty.cateogry_id !=' 14]]
```

Or use [the joins array](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) of the query.

Comment: I have forgot to mention that Category is a Tree. So I want to get all Novelty for Category = 13 and its children. I have convention that all child categories have number begining with 13. Bu now I see that condition would be wrong until i'll make id to sort in linguistic order. Anyway. I want to get all Novelties for category = 13 and its children

Comment: "I have convention that all child categories have number begining with 13." This doesn't sound like any of both supported types (parent-child, nested set) of tree structures of the behavior. However, use joins and not the containable behavior to build the queries you need.